# Problem with submenus

Tags: 7, theming

I am new at Drupal , and I am using version 7.43. I have already installed Bootstrap, and now I am defining the menus. But to realize Multilevel submenus I need the folder of `bootstrap_subtheme`

I searched but I couldn't find that folder, I found just the Bootstrap folder.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create such sub-theme folder manually. The folder name you'd use for it will be the machine name of your subtheme.

For more details, refer to:

- "[Creating a sub-theme](https://www.drupal.org/node/225125)" (= Community documentation that applies to any sub-theme).
- "[Sub-theming](http://drupal-bootstrap.org/api/bootstrap/docs!subtheme!README.md/group/subtheme/7)" (= documentation about sub-theming specific to Drupal's [Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) theme).

If you prefer to look at a great (I think) example of a (contributed) Bootstrap sub-theme, then have a look at the [Bootstrap Business](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_business) theme.